# Problem naming certain arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

There's something I'm doing wrong in a certain diagram, and I can't seem to figure out how to name an arrow that bends. Here's a MWE (both with the package tikzcd and tikz + library cd the same error appears:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
        & & A\ar{dl}\arrow[dll, bend right] &\\
        B & C\lar[dashed]{\exists!\Phi} & & D\ar[hook]{ul}\ar{dl}\\
        & & E\ar[hook]{ul}\ar[ull, hook, bend left] &
\end{tikzcd}
```

I need to name the arrow A -> B, but whenever I type `\arrow[dll, bend right "\psi"]`, for example, an error message comes up, indicating that no color named $\psi$ exists (yeah, weird).

How do I circumvent this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You only forgot a comma, i.e. `bend right` and the label need to be separated by a comma. (If you want, we can delete these posts.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
        & & A\ar{dl}\arrow[dll, bend right,"\psi" '] &\\
        B & C\lar[dashed]{\exists!\Phi} & & D\ar[hook]{ul}\ar{dl}\\
        & & E\ar[hook]{ul}\ar[ull, hook, bend left] &
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]